# About T.I. subgroups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. $H$ is called T.I subgroup if for every $g\in G$, $H\cap H^g=1$ or $H\cap H^g=H$.

I want to know some fundemantel and basic properties of such subgroups. I s there any source or theorem ?

For example image of T.I subgroup need not to be T.I. Is there any condition which supply this ?

Any reference sor source are welcome.

Comment: What's $H^g$???

Comment: It is a very comman and standart notation. It means $g^{-1}Hg$.

Comment: You may want to check "Frobenius Groups" . Certainly any normal subgroup $\;H\;$ fuflills the second condition $\;H^g\cap H=H\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo: Thank you. It happens when $N_G(H)=H$ and $H$ is T.I subgroup. But I want to deal with in general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read I.M. Isaacs'book *Character Theory of Finite Groups*, [Chapter 7](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U-HmNAOdnkkC&pg=PA101&dq=TI%20sets%20and%20exceptional%20characters&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz1P3fkbHLAhWEa5oKHRIADnAQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=TI%20sets%20and%20exceptional%20characters&f=false). The TI sets have a relationship with so-called Frobenius Groups as was remarked by Joanperno.